# What's the point of a key-value pair in a binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

What exactly is the point of having a key-value pair in a binary search tree? Can someone give an example of one such instance? Because in the stl set container, I don't explicitly assign a key-value pair.

I'm new to BSTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key could be a simple value used to insert, find or delete a node from the tree. Value could be the data a node holds. For example, a key can be username while value can be user information like Name, surname, age, location, preferences ...

Comment: So can you do a query like "how many people are under 65 years old with a name starting with b through x?"

Comment: Yes. The key helps find people starting with b through x. You need extra check on those people for their age. This can be easy to check while traversing from b to x

Comment: So it's linear in the amount of reported nodes?

Comment: If there are 5 people between b ad x then you have to check 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

BST is built to provide quick querying on a specific property of a treeNode.

If I want to get the staffs whose salary is higher than $100,000.

Build the BST, use salary as key of the tree nodes and put other information like age, address, whatever in the value.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the key is that given some node `S` as a starting point all nodes (and their keys) to the left of `S` are less than the key value of `S` and all nodes (and their keys) to the right of `S` are greater than the key value of `S`

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't you usually want the key to be the same as value? (Eg the stl set). What would be the benefits of differentiating them?

Comment: @user1959272 why would you want to store duplicate data?

Answer (score 0):

Same as any data structure using (key, value) pairs: you probably want to be able to access value data while referencing each value by its key. All that not using a hash of the value gets you is some additional flexibility. Not sure what you mean by "point"... languages give you tools to solve problems in different ways, and if one of those ways is using (key, value) pairs in a binary search tree, why not use it?